# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null laravel 5.3.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am trying to get the table (Company) primary key id value in table (Branch) as a foreign key. And both tables (Company , Branch) primary keys id values in the table (Medicine) as a foreign keys. But when i submit these Medicine form the error is Occured :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'company_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `medicines`
>   (`company_id`, `branch_id`, `medicines_name`, `type`, `potency`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 1, panadol, tablet, 23mg,
>   2017-02-27 13:03:01, 2017-02-27 13:03:01))

Controller:

```
class MedicineController extends Controller
{
    public function getmedicineform(){

        $company = Company::all();
        $branch = Branch::all();
        return view("medicinesdetails.addProduct")->with('company', $company)->with('branch',$branch);
    }

    public function saveMedinfo(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'product_name' => 'required',
            'product_type' =>'required',
            'potency' =>'required',
        ]);
        if($validator->passes()){
            $med = new Medicine();
            $med->company_id = $request->company_id;
            $med->branch_id = $request->branch_id;
            $med->medicines_name = $request->product_name;
            $med->type = $request->product_type;
            $med->potency = $request->potency;
            if($med->save()){
                $request->session()->flash('message','Successfully Save!!');
                return redirect('/add/product');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/add/product')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal product-form" action="/add/product" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @foreach($company as $compny)
                    <input type="hidden" name= company_id" value="{{$compny->id}}">
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @foreach($branch as $brnch)
                    <input type="hidden" name="branch_id" value="{{$brnch->id}}">
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" placeholder="Product Name">
                @if($errors->has('product_name'))
                    {{$errors->first('product_name')}}
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product Type</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" name="product_type">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="tablet">Tablet</option>
                    <option value="syrup">Syrup</option>
                    <option value="injectable">Injectable</option>
                </select>
                @if($errors->has('product_type'))
                    {{$errors->first('product_type')}}
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Potency</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="potency" placeholder="Potency">
                @if($errors->has('potency'))
                    {{$errors->first('potency')}}
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>

        @if(Session::has('message'))
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <button type="submit" value="Add product" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{csrf_field()}}
    </form>
```

Comment: Seems like `$request->company_id;` is not being set and is therefore `NULL` so when you print your query you've got `values (, 1, panadol` (note it starts with a comma)... and since there's a foreign key constraint that means that company id *cannot* be `NULL` it's failing - view your HTML source to see what the actual value is on that `<input ... name="company_id" ... />`